# Importar javascript en TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, javascript-import

Estoy inciando en typescript y para comenzar a trabajar voy a ir pasando algunos de mis javascript de un proyecto que tengo corriendo.

para esto comencé con mi Main.js cambiandole el nombre a .ts y moviendolo a una carpeta donde tendre todo el source typeScript (dentro del mismo proyecto)

Dentro de mi archivo main hago referencias a otras clases, pongo aqui parte del codigo:

```
var SiteController=function() {
    this.eventManager = new EventManager(this);
}
```

El problema es que typescript dice que no puede encontrar EventManager.

Lo que no sé es si no tengo que hacer algún tipo de `import` de todos los javascript que tengo en mi otra carpeta.
El error que me tira es el siguiente:

> file:
>   'file:///d%3A/_PROYECTOS/turner/TURNER_WB_TBBT_TriviaFan/deploy/js/typeScript/SiteController.ts'
>   severity: 'Error' message: 'Cannot find name 'EventManager'.' source:
>   'ts'

Imagino que deberia ser algo como

> import '../js/bin/';

pero la verad que desconozco como tengo que hacer para importar todas mis clases javascript ya sean propias o de otras librerias y no tener este error

la estructura de carpetas que manejo es:

```
deploy
deploy/js
deploy/js/typeScript
deploy/js/bin
```

dentro de typescript estan los archivos .ts
y dentro de `bin` hay carpetas con librerias de terceros o clases propias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que importar la clase `EventManager` :

```
import {EventManager} from '../RUTA';
```

Si quisieras importar todas las clases de un `namespace` deberia estar hecho asi :

MisClases.ts

```
export namespace clase{
    export class EventManager {
        //tu codigo
    }
    export class OtraClase { 
        //tu codigo
    }
}
```

Y para importarlas

```
import * as misClases from './MisClases';
```

Para utilizarlas

```
let eventManager = misClases.clase.EventManager();
```

Comment: hay forma de importar todas las clases automaticamente?
algo como 

import {*} from '../bin';

gracias!

Comment: @Pablo listo, echale un ojo!

Comment: voy con otra pregunta sobre este mismo feed porque no me deja agregar tanto texto en un comentario

Comment: Es que si no quieres crear namespaces para tus clases, no es posible poder importarlas todas de una sola vez.

Comment: gracias la respuesta me sirvió ya que me las esta importando si las agrego de a una, pense que se podria importar todo un paquete de clases sin agregarle los namespace, desde alguna configuracion, ahora, sabes que es este error que me esta dando al usar el import:

file: 'file:///d%3A/_PROYECTOS/turner/TURNER_WB_TBBT_TriviaFan/deploy/js/typeScript/SiteController.ts'
severity: 'Error'
message: 'Module '../bin/EventManager.js' was resolved to 'd:/_PROYECTOS/turner/TURNER_WB_TBBT_TriviaFan/deploy/js/bin/EventManager.js', but '--allowJs' is not set.'
at: '2,28'
source: 'ts'

Comment: verificaste que en tu archivo `tsconfig.json` este `allowJs : true` ???

Comment: Y ojo con los archivos que intentes ocupar tanto en tus clases como en los controladores, porque te esta reclamando por la extension .js del `EventManager.js` cuando deberia ser `EventManager.ts`

Comment: si lo tengo habilitado, voy a abrir una nueva pregunta por este tema para no agregar basura a este feed, gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

gracias por ayudar, parte ya me sirvio pero no me termina de convencer la forma de importarlas desde el namespace, el motivo es que yo ya tengo muchisimos archivos de clases con su codigo en diferentes archivos y mi idea es ir pasando el proyecto de a poco a typescript, si tengo que agregar o modificar todas las llamadas de las clases voy a tener que refactorizar mucho codigo, a no ser que no este entiendo bien la mecanica para hacerlo.

por lo cual por ahora lo estoy haciendo asi:
import {EventManager} from '../bin/EventManager.js';

el problema que tengo es que me tira este error:

```
file: 'file:///d%3A/_PROYECTOS/turner/TURNER_WB_TBBT_TriviaFan/deploy/js/typeScript/SiteController.ts'
severity: 'Error'
message: 'Module '../bin/EventManager.js' was resolved to 'd:/_PROYECTOS/tur/T_WB_TBBT_TriviaFan/deploy/js/bin/EventManager.js', but '--allowJs' is not set.'
at: '1,28'
source: 'ts'
```